# How can generate a raw file from multi-band tif file?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gdal

I try open a tif image with 16-bit per pixel and multi-band to convert it in a raw file. I'm using PIL with the next commands `i = Image.open('image.tif')` and after I use `rawData = i.tostring()`. It doesn't work with multi-band tif image.

The error is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

The directory contains the file.

How I must do it ?

Comment: Your TIFF file must be using a format PIL doesn't recognize. Make sure it [falls in the supported criteria](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-tiff.htm).

Comment: And there aren't other library, like Gdal, for do it ?

Comment: PIL doesn't support 16-bits per pixel see [Concepts](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/concepts.htm).

Comment: Yes, but I can open a 16-bit tif image with a single band. However, multi-band images no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL is pretty good at opening multiband rasters, and supports [11 different band types](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html), including int16.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

ds = gdal.Open('image.tif')

# loop through each band
for bi in range(ds.RasterCount):
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(bi + 1)
    # Read this band into a 2D NumPy array
    ar = band.ReadAsArray()
    print('Band %d has type %s'%(bi + 1, ar.dtype))
    raw = ar.tostring()
```